# How can I pass multiple properties to the PulseAudio module parameter source_output_properties?

Tags: pulseaudio

Many PulseAudio modules accept a property list as an argument, but I couldn't find any documentation about the format of that list, and all examples I could find only pass a single property. Here's what I would like to do:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=… sink=… \
    source_output_properties='module-stream-restore.id="loopback" media.name="foo"'
```

This invocation results in the unhelpful error message

```
Failure: Module initialisation failed
```

The syslog contains the marginally more helpful

```
module-loopback.c: Failed to parse module arguments
```

Passing either of these parameters individually works fine, so the problem is passing both of them at once. I tried various formats, including passing the `source_output_properties` parameter twice, but always got the same error.

I'm aware that I can use `pacmd` to change the properties of the source output after loading the module, but that's far more complex to script in a shell script, since you need to find the index of the new source output.

Since there is no doucmentation how to do this, I peeked at the source code, and the [function to parse the property list](https://github.com/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/blob/4e3a080d7699732be9c522be9a96d851f97fbf11/src/pulse/proplist.c#L450) definitely looks like it should accept the parameter list in the format I provided.

Any clues how to do this?

I'm using PulseAudio version 13.0.

Comment: Since this issue is not related to Ubuntu, you may find better support at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @K7AAY I've seen a lot more questions about PulseAudio here than on Unix & Linux, so I asked here. If nobody can help, I'll try the PulseAudio mailing list.

Comment: I think it's a syntax problem, from the examples I see in the [documention](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-loopback), you need to separate multiple options for one property with commas. `source_output_properties=module-stream-restore.id=loopback,media.name=foo`

Comment: @mook765 The syntax is what I'm asking for. If I use exactly what you have, I get a single property with the key `module-stream-restore.id` and the value `loopback,media.name=foo`. If I use quotes around the values, I get the same error as in the question. Moreover, the source code I linked suggests that I need to separate properties with whitespace. And finally, I can't find any examples in the documentation – neither on the page you linked nor anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By educated guessing based on the source code, I found the following two working ways of passing multiple properties:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source_output_properties="'foo=\"bar\" baz=\"gloink\"'"
pactl load-module module-loopback source_output_properties='foo="bar"baz="gloink"'
```

Apparently PulseAudio is applying its own quote parsing, which interacts in a broken way with the shell's quote parsing.

Another way around this problem suitable for shell scripts is using `pacmd` instead:

```
pacmd <<EOF
load-module module-loopback source_output_properties='foo="bar" baz="gloink"'
EOF
```

This way we can avoid the shell's quote parsing to restore some sanity.

None of this seems to be doucmented anywhere, so I [filed a bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/891).